# Is it possible to create an Outlook rule to send all messages to junk if a certain header is missing?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention, rules

We have a spam filter that adds a header that indicates that the message has gone through the filter. In the Outlook client, is it possible to create a rule that sends all email to the junk folder if that header is missing?

Answer (score 1):

Good question; i.e., *whitelist* email that has been verified.
A possible workaround, if you don't get a better, single-step, answer:

[Create *two* rules](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/create-rule-based-on-email-header/d6a43199-3e77-4fa3-8e40-bb0dfe4ad7f0):

1. The first to activate should move all messages with the correct header indicating the messages has been checked to a new folder, e.g., *Validated*.
2. The second should move the remaining messages in the *Inbox* to *Spam*, or perhaps another new folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Exchange or Microsoft365, you can set up whitelisting by email headers, refer to this article:
[Whitelisting by Email Header in Exchange 2013, 2016, or Microsoft 365](https://%20setting%20up%20whitelisting%20by%20email%20headers)

Comment: Do you think my reply is helpful? If so, please accept it as answer to help other people.